# NetBeans 7.2 git push error

Tags: git, ssh, netbeans-7

I have set up a new git repository on my ubuntu server. I made some initial commits and successfully cloned the repository from my mac over ssh. When trying to push the changes I made on the mac I am getting the following error:

```
error occurred during unpacking on the remote end: unpack-objects abnormal exit
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 4):

We have had the same problem - Windows PCs using Netbeans pushing to a RHEL server with the main repo.

The only solution I have found so far is to run `git fsck`, `git prune` and `git repack remote/origin/master` followed by a final `git fsck`. The first `git fsck` will show that you have one or more dangling commits and the subsequent commands clean up the repo and you'll then be able to push from Netbeans. I have tried to inspect these but they appear to be nonexistent, so it's a mystery where they come from. The problem doesn't occur if I push from another Linux box, from the command line. All this is over SSH.

It's fine when just one user is pushing to the repo, but as soon as someone else does, then the first user will (after doing a pull to be non-fast-forward) get this error. I suspect Netbeans is doing something odd with the push but I don't know what.

**EDIT:**

This is basically to do with WRITE privileges as per the comment to this answer, but I've solved it by doing the following
(assuming that "developers" is our group that we want to allow to push and that example.com.git is the repo)

```
[tim@dev git]# chgrp -R developers example.com.git
[tim@dev git]# chmod -R g+swX example.com.git
```

See [this answer at Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/26954/how-do-i-share-a-git-repository-with-multiple-users-on-a-machine) for more info

Comment: In my case the error was caused by the SSH configuration. The configured users did not have the necessary rights to WRITE to the git folder. After the WRITE privileges were added everything worked!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by restarting ssh daemon on git server

```
# service sshd restart
```